# S3 identifying files that got overwritten without versioning being enabled

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

So we uploaded about 2000 files into a bucket, using boto3, where there's no versioning enabled.

However, some of those files were already in the bucket by the same name. Is there a name to check which of those files were already in the bucket before being uploaded? The bucket has no versioning enabled which is the issue here.

We did not initially create a list of the file contents of the bucket.

Comment: Is the server access log enabled on the bucket?

Comment: Just checked and it looks like this isn't enabled either!

Comment: The only other way would be if you have [CloudTrial for your bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html) enabled, and it recorded all the uploads.

Comment: ^If the CloudTrail isn't enabled either, chances are you have to guess based on LastModifiedDate.